# Fitting a long list of studies in Metafor Forestplot to make it readable

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm trying to do a forest plot using metafor::forest. The problem is that because I have over 100 studies the output is unreadable because the rows blend together and overlap unless I choose a very small font (in which case you also can't read it).

**Any ideas on how to plot this so that the font is large enough to be read without having all rows overlap?**

Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(metafor)

res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)

par(mar = c(6, 6, 6, 6))
forest(res, addpred=T, header=TRUE, atransf=exp, at=log(c(.05, 0.5, 5, 15)),  xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-3,190), cex=.75)
```

This is the output
[image]

The only way it doesn't overlap is with cex = .05, but it is of course impossible to see anything:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not known the library nor the data, and cannot reproduce your example, but, for case, try using another output device:

```
png("file.png" , width = 480, height = 4000)
plot(runif(100))
dev.off()
```

Then see result file in current (`getwd()`) directory.